# Getting the Value of Checked Checbox returns undefined in JavaScript/ASP.NET VB

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have a `Checkbox` which has 10 items inside `GridView`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="chkGrid" name = "sample1" class = "messageCheckbox" runat="server"    onclick="javascript:SelectCheckedItem(this)" Text = '<%# Bind("status_desc") %>'  />
</ItemTemplate>
```

What I want is to get the values of the `CheckBox` inside the `GridView`. I am getting the values if I used VB. What I want is getting it via JavaScript. Here is my code for the JavaScript:

```
function SelectCheckedItem(itemchk) {
            debugger
            var gvcheck = document.getElementById('gvDetails'); //This is the ID of the GridView
            if (itemchk.checked) {
                var checkedValue = $('messageCheckbox:checked').val();
                alert(checkedValue);
            }

            else {

                }
            }

        }
```

But I am getting undefined value.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkGrid" Text="Status" runat="server" />
```

Will be rendered something like the following (notice the `id` change because of `runat="server"`)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkGrid_ctl01" />
<label for="chkGrid_ctl01">Status</label>
```

So to get the text in the `label` for each checkbox you will need to loop through the checkboxes and find the adjacent label.

To get the `label` for just the clicked checkbox, you can do something like

```
function SelectCheckedItem(itemchk) {
    if (itemchk.checked) {
        var checkedValue = $(itemchk)
            .siblings('label[for="' + itemchk.id '"]')
            .text();
        console.log(checkedValue);
    }
}
```

But to get all the labels, you will have to loop through each checkbox with class `.messageCheckbox`

```
function SelectCheckedItem() {
    $('.messageCheckbox:checked').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).siblings('label[for="' + itemchk.id '"]').text());
    });
}
```

Comment: You mean like this:
//JS Code
function SelectCheckedItem() {
            $('.messageCheckbox:checked').each(function () {
                console.log($(this).siblings('label[for="' + itemchk.id '"]').text());
            });
        }

//View
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkGrid" class = "messageCheckbox" runat="server" onclick="javascript:SelectCheckedItem(this)" Text = '<%# Bind("status_desc") %>'  /></ItemTemplate>

Comment: it returns `'on'` value

Comment: Because `<%# Bind("status_desc") %>` returns `'on'` for the checkbox text?

Comment: nope. it returns text like "processed", "unprocessed" and so on

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the GridView most likely isn't `gvDetails` as .NET adds a whole extra string into your IDs. You need to look into using `gvDetails.ClientID` on your server side

```
var gvcheck = document.getElementById(<% gvDetails.ClientID %>); // This is the generated ID of the GridView
```